# Why is it not accepting data in a function

Tags: python, excel

I was making a security application when I got stuck at this.
The application catches scammers by scanning their data and reports it to the nearest police station. Currently it is on the login page and almost done for the first part. But The issue is that it is not inputting the values into the sheet .On **Individual run**, It works fine but when I import qwerty and use it, it doesn't ake values. Please help here too

````
        from tkinter import *
        from tkinter.font import Font
        from exlsx import qwerty
        
       
        root = Tk()
        
        
        def abcd():
            def register():
                abra = [userlvalue.get(), passvalue.get(), namevalue.get(), mobilevalue.get(), mailvalue.get(), locvalue.get()]
        
                qwerty(abra)
                print(abra)
        
            RRoot = Toplevel(root)
        
            RRoot.geometry('1200x1100')
            RRoot.title('Hide your Identity')
        
            Fontu = Font(
                family='ZCOOL KuaiLe',
                size=25
        
            )
        
            a = Label(RRoot, text='Hide your Identity using The World\'s most efficient Identity hider', font=Fontu, bg='blue',
                      fg='white')
            a.pack(anchor=N)
        
            lab = Label(RRoot, text='Enter Username', font=('Times', 20, 'normal'))
            lab.pack(anchor=N, pady=40)
        
            Useprid = Entry(RRoot, width=50)
        
            Useprid.pack(anchor=N)
        
            userlvalue = StringVar()
        
            labp = Label(RRoot, text='Enter Password', font=('Times', 20, 'normal'))
            labp.pack(anchor=N, pady=40)
        
            Usewrid = Entry(RRoot, width=50)
        
            Usewrid.pack(anchor=N)
            Usewrid.config(show='@')
        
            passvalue = StringVar()
        
            labn = Label(RRoot, text='Enter Name', font=('Times', 20, 'normal'))
            labn.pack(anchor=N, pady=40)
        
            namedid = Entry(RRoot, width=50)
        
            namedid.pack(anchor=N)
        
            labm = Label(RRoot, text='Enter Mobile', font=('Times', 20, 'normal'))
            labm.pack(anchor=N, pady=40)
        
            mobiled = Entry(RRoot, width=50)
        
            mobiled.pack(anchor=N)
        
            namevalue = StringVar()
        
            labe = Label(RRoot, text='Enter Email', font=('Times', 20, 'normal'))
            labe.pack(anchor=N, pady=40)
        
            mailrid = Entry(RRoot, width=50)
        
            mailrid.pack(anchor=N)
        
            mailvalue = StringVar()
        
            mobilevalue = StringVar()
        
            labl = Label(RRoot, text='Enter City', font=('Times', 20, 'normal'))
            labl.pack(anchor=N, pady=40)
        
            locrid = Entry(RRoot, width=50)
        
            locrid.pack(anchor=N)
        
            locvalue = StringVar()
        
            Btn = Button(RRoot, text='Submit', font=('Algerian', 20, 'normal'), command=register)
            Btn.pack(anchor=N, pady=40)
        
           
        
        
        def qwe():
            s = uservalue.get()
            blow = Passvalue.get()
            qwerty(s, blow)
        
        
        root.geometry('1200x1100')
        root.title('Hide your Identity')
        
        Fontu = Font(
            family='ZCOOL KuaiLe',
            size=25
        
        )
        
        a = Label(text='Hide your Identity using The World\'s most efficient Identity hider', font=Fontu, bg='blue',
                  fg='white')
        a.pack(anchor=N)
        
        lab = Label(text='Enter Username', font=('Times', 20, 'normal'))
        lab.pack(anchor=N, pady=50)
        
        Useprid = Entry(root, width=50)
        
        Useprid.pack(anchor=N)
        
        uservalue = StringVar()
        
        labp = Label(text='Enter Password', font=('Times', 20, 'normal'))
        labp.pack(anchor=N, pady=50)
        
        Usewrid = Entry(root, width=50)
        
        Usewrid.pack(anchor=N)
        Usewrid.config(show='@')
        
        Passvalue = StringVar()
        
        Btn = Button(root, text='Submit', font=('Algerian', 20, 'normal'), command=qwe)
        Btn.pack(anchor=N, pady=50)
        
        rBtn = Button(root, text='Register', font=('Arial', 20, 'normal'), command=abcd)
        rBtn.pack(anchor=N, pady=50)
        
        root.mainloop()```

 #Qwerty code

    ```from openpyxl import Workbook
    
    
    def qwerty(list):
        Wors = Workbook()
        Worc = Wors.create_sheet('Scam data')
    
        heaf = ['Username', 'Password','Name', "Mobile", 'Scammed Number of People', 'Total Scammed Amount', 'Email', 'Location']
        jufu = [0, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', "G","H"]
        v = []
    
        for i in range(1, 9):
            v.append(i)
        for j in range(0, 8):
            concell = jufu[v[j]] + '1'
            Worc[concell].value = heaf[j]
    
        bcd = []
        bcd.append(123)
        print(bcd)
    
    
    
        def uiop(list):
            maxi = Worc.max_row
            #print(maxi)
    
            '''for row, entry in enumerate(list, start=1):
                Worc.cell(row=row + maxi, column=1, value=entry)'''
            #tuuple = tuple(list)
            for vakue in range(0, 6):
                Worc.append(tuple(list))
        uiop(list = list)
        Wors.save('scamdeaa.xlsx')

**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python divane\Scammerbeware\scambeware.py", line 5, in <module>
    qwerty()
TypeError: qwerty() missing 1 required positional argument: 'list'**

Please help
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on line 5 `qwerty()` expecting a positional argument, pass an argument to it.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the function without any arguments (`qwerty()`), but the function requires a list argument, so you should call it like this:

```
qwerty(myList)
```